# Can we apply 2 different queries with OR condition to sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx

I have below 2 queries

```
$partialQuery1 = " @co1 txt1 @col2 txt2 @col3 txt3";
$partialQuery2 = " @co1 txt4 @col2 txt5 @col3 txt6";
```

Now, I want to apply OR like below

```
$partialQuery3 = $partialQuery1 . " OR(|) " . $partialQuery2;
$cl->Query(partialQuery3, "indexer");
```

This is giving me zero (0) resuts for now. I am not sure whether it is possible or not in sphinx?

**Note** : I don't want use below approach

```
$partialQuery = " @col (txt1 | txt4) ....";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$partialQuery3 = "(". $partialQuery1 . ") | (" . $partialQuery2 . ")";
```

The OR operator is simply a pipe char `|` - the actual word OR is not valid.

Operator precedence means would ALSO need brackets around each partquery (othrwise wouild be `(txt3 | txt4)` the the middle).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Give me a try on this